# Mac wakes up from sleep every two hours on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: sleep-wake, mac-mini, macos, console

Since upgrading to the first stable release of Mac OS X Yosemite a few days ago, my Mac Mini wakes up roughly every two hours from sleep for about a minute, then goes back to sleep. This is particularly annoying at night since I sleep my Mac, and it's in the bedroom, so I notice when it turns on.

In my Console, here's some of the lines from it from when it wakes up:

```
14/10/19 6:48:06.000 am kernel[0]: Wake reason: RTC (Alarm)
14/10/19 6:48:06.000 am kernel[0]: RTC: Maintenance 2014/10/19 10:48:06, sleep 2014/10/19 09:00:12
14/10/19 6:48:06.001 am SyncServer[910]: [0x7fdd69c19d80] |SyncServer|Warning| Refreshing watchdog because of a calendar time change alert.
14/10/19 6:48:06.000 am kernel[0]: Previous sleep cause: 5
14/10/19 6:48:06.000 am kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltNHIType2::prePCIWake - power up complete - took 1 us
14/10/19 6:48:06.000 am kernel[0]: The USB device USB 3.0 HUB (Port 1 of Hub at 0x15000000) may have caused a wake by issuing a remote wakeup (1)
```

From the last line, yes, I've got a USB 3 hub plugged in to my USB 3 port on the Mac. But there are no devices plugged into the hub. Nevertheless, I'll try unplugging it tonight, but I suspect it won't make a difference.

Also, I've already disabled "Wake from network access", disabled "Power Nap", and pretty much disabled everything else in the "Energy Saver" system preferences pane.

When I run `pmset -g`, I get:

```
Active Profiles:
AC Power    -1*
Currently in use:
 standby              1
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 womp                 0
 autorestart          0
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 darkwakes            0
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            0
 sleep                0 (sleep prevented by iMovie, coreaudiod, iTunes, AddressBookSour)
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 hibernatemode        0
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         60
 standbydelay         4200
```

---

I often have wake problems with my Mac, especially after upgrading to a new OS, and this time is no exception:

1. [OS X Mavericks wakes my Mac from sleep every hour or so](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107571/os-x-mavericks-wakes-my-mac-from-sleep-every-hour-or-so)
2. [Mac wakes up from sleep every night and then goes back to sleep immediately](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103962/mac-wakes-up-from-sleep-every-night-and-then-goes-back-to-sleep-immediately)

Comment: What does your pmset -g looks like?

Comment: I pasted the pmset -g results above.

Comment: see my updated answer and thanks for pmset (you might want to clean that up anyway)

Comment: Clean up, in what way? I'll be glad to do so but I'm not sure what I need to do.

Comment: The items preventing the sleep mode is a different question -nothing to do with your RTC wake. Usually they are simple to deal with by terminating the applications in question. To see details run "pmset -g assertions"

Comment: Have you simply tried to open 'System Preferences/Energy Saver' and disable 'Wake for WiFi Network access'?  that seems to be the first port of call...

Comment: Yes, I already said I disabled that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to have fixed itself after updating to [Yosemite 10.10.2, released on January 28, 2015](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1786). The notes don't mention anything regarding sleep or wake but it seems to have fixed it regardless.

Comment: It's now happening for me again on 10.11.4.

Answer (score 4):

Since com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist got replaced by com.apple.discoveryd.plist after Yosemite Beta, there is another solution for your Problem.

All you have to do is to run following command in your terminal:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :ProgramArguments: string --no-multicast" \ 
         /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist
```

And reboot your system and it should be gone.

Like also described here: http://ispire.me/fix-yosemite-rtc-alarm-wakeup-issue/

You just have to know that services relying on multicast might not work properly anymore after this change.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: @patrix Better now?

Comment: When I unload discoveryd and load mDNSResponder, I irreparably lose connection to the Internet. I don't understand what I might be doing wrong… but I cannot apply the fix due to this.

Comment: @user97535: Yosemite replaced mDNSResponder with discoveryd.

Comment: Don't use `--no-multicast` right now if you use WiFi, it breaks auto-connecting to remembered networks and the status bar icon.  Apple has been notified.  Rebooting is absolutely unnecessary, just `sudo launchctl unload` / `load` the plist.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It should work on 10.10.4 or later. Enter the following in Terminal and then restart your Mac:

```
sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist ProgramArguments -array-add -DisableSleepProxyClient
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution approach using the tool `SleepWatcher` by Bernhard Baehr. To install SleepWatcher, use:

```
brew install sleepwatcher
```

`com.apple.discoveryd` is just getting unloaded before sleep and loaded again after wake (see post by tseug in ["Wake reason: RTC (Alarm) - how to deactivate?"](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/300072-wake-reason-rtc-alarm-how-to-deactivate/page-5#entry2080144)). Edit the following config files as path suggested in comments and give some of the files execution permission:

```
# author: tseug (see link above)
# /Library/LaunchDaemons/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher.plist

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/usr/local/sbin/sleepwatcher</string>
                <string>-V</string>
                <string>-s /etc/rc.sleep</string>
                <string>-w /etc/rc.wakeup</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>


# /etc/rc.sleep
# chmod +x /etc/rc.sleep

#!/bin/sh
# Unload discoveryd to disable maintenance wakeup every two hours
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist


# /etc/rc.wakeup
# chmod +x /etc/rc.wakeup

#!/bin/sh
# Load discoveryd to enable network
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist
```